# How to replace elements in an array in elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to replace all occurrences of 2 with 3.I want to do this without using the value of the index because that would be hardcoding. What I have so far is:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,2,34,2]

replace_at(list, index, value)

Enum.each list, fn(x) ->
if x==2 do
  replace_at(list, index, 3)
end

Enum.each list, fn(x) ->
IO.puts x
end
```

Answer (score 10):

In Elixir, you do not have arrays, but [linked list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html). If you simply want to replace all ocurrences of 2 with 3, you can use the [map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) function, of the `Enum` module like this:

```
iex(1)> Enum.map(list, fn x -> if x == 2, do: 3, else: x end)
[1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 34, 3]
```

You could also use pattern matching:

```
iex(1)> Enum.map(list, fn
...(1)> 2 -> 3
...(1)> x -> x
...(1)> end)
```

Comment: You can even one-line it: `Enum.map(list, fn 2 -> 3; x -> x end)` (but not for long, as the formatter will convert it to multi-line by default if you use it).

Answer (score 4):

It is essential to know that Elixir is immutable, so you cannot replace values in a list; actually, you create a new list.

You can use the map method from [Enum](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module, where you can found a bunch of algorithms to deal with enumerables.

```
iex(2)> [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 34, 2] |> Enum.map(fn
...(2)>   2 -> 3
...(2)>   other -> other
...(2)> end)
[1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 34, 3]
```

A method with this implementation could be like the code below:

```
defmodule Replace do

  def replace_all(list, from, to) do
    list
    |> Enum.map(fn
      ^from -> to
      other -> other
    end)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have arrays, and access by index is costly.

If you still want to accomplish it, [`Enum.with_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2) is your friend.

```rb
replace_at = fn list, index, value -> 
  list
  |> Enum.with_index()
  |> Enum.map(fn
    {_, ^index} -> value # match index
    {value, _} -> value  # anything else   
  end)
end
```

And use it like

```rb
# index      0  1  2  3  4  5   6  
replace_at.([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 34, 2], 2, 42)
#⇒ [1, 2, 42, 4, 2, 34, 2]
```

---

Replacing all 2s has nothing to do with the index, one does not need the index to do it. Just use `Enum.map/2` out of the box.

---

Also, you should learn that `Enum.each/2` does not modify anything ever.

Comment: Re: replace_at: `List.replace_at/3` would do the same out of the box and be more efficient I believe, since it should be able to reuse the right part of the list and does not have to walk the full list (but it is still costly and not equivalent to an array).

Comment: The purpose of this answer was mostly to show how we deal with indices in lists if needed. `Enum.reduce_while/3` instead of `Enum.map/2` and we’ll get to the `List.replace_at/3` implementation. Also, `put_in/3` + `Access.at/2`.