# How to filter a list by modulus in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have an array

```
arr=[1,2,14,1,27]
```

I want to make a new array called arr1 that will stores all the values of arr that will equal to 1 when you take the modulus of it.So,

```
arr2=[1,14,1,27]
```

Since 1 mod 13, 14 mod 13, and 27 mod 13 all equal to 1.

Comment: Can you please stop asking about arrays, which the answers to the previous questions you've asked over the last few days, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696409/how-to-replace-elements-in-an-array-in-elixir) point out don't exist in Elixir (unless you use the :array module). It gives the impression you are not learning from the answers. Elixir has lists, not arrays. You should also show us the code you've already attempted before asking the question.

Comment: I hope that comment didn't drive them to delete their account. . BTW [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790570/modulo-operator-in-elixir) is the question about modulus.

Comment: The difference between Arrays and LinkedLists may not be that easy to understand or even recognize for a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` with `modulo` rem(x, 13) == 1

```
arr=[1,2,14,1,27]
arr2 = Enum.filter(arr, fn x -> rem(x, 13) == 1 end)
IO.inspect  arr
IO.inspect  arr2
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 14, 1, 27]
[1, 14, 1, 27]
```

Answer (score 6):

This kind of task is better done with [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension, which is waaaaay more powerful than `Enum.filter/2`.

```rb
for i <- [1, 2, 14, 1, 27], rem(i, 13) == 1, do: i
#⇒ [1, 14, 1, 27]
```